# I can not update my entity using Hibernate, Spring MVC, Thymleaf

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data, thymeleaf

Hello I want to update User entity, so in the form edit.html i'm using thymeleaf:

```
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/{id}/edit(id=${user.id})}"
                            th:object="${user}" method="post">
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"
                                    th:value="${user.firstName}" name="firstName" id="firstName"
                                    class="form-control" /> <label class="active" for="firstName">Prénom</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}"
                                    th:value="${user.lastName}" name="lastName" id="lastName"
                                    class="form-control" /> <label class="active" for="lastName">Nom</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" th:value="${user.email}"
                                    name="email" id="email" class="form-control" /> <label
                                    class="active" for="email">email</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" th:field="*{password}"
                                    th:value="${user.password}" name="password" id="password"
                                    class="form-control" /> <label class="active" for="password">mot
                                    de passe</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" th:field="*{occupation}"
                                    th:value="${user.occupation}" name="occupation" id="occupation"
                                    class="form-control" /> <label class="active" for="occupation">profession</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" th:field="*{ville}" th:value="${user.ville}"
                                    name="ville" id="ville" class="form-control" /> <label
                                    class="active" for="ville">ville</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input class="btn btn-sm btn-primary waves-effect btn-rounded"
                                    type="submit" value="modifier" />
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

**User.java:**

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userName;
    private int age;
    private String ville;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String phone;
    private String company;
    private String occupation;
    private String img_profil;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private Set<Discussion> discussion;
```

**UserController.java**

```
@GetMapping("/{userName}/edit")
public String editUser(@PathVariable String userName, Model model) {
    User user = ur.findByUserName(userName).get(0);
    model.addAttribute(user);
    return "edit";
}

@PostMapping("/{id}/edit")
public String updateUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    user = ur.findOne(id);
    ur.save(user);
    return "redirect:/find/" + user.getUserName();
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    List<User> findByUserName(String userName);

}
```

**PROBLEM is** in the console I do not see update request (generated by Hibernate), nothing is changed on the database.

Comment: You're getting a user from the database, and then saving the user you just got. So there's nothing to be saved.

Comment: I think you're right, so how can I update my entity user ?

Comment: The same way you're doing, but by modifying some of it properties before saving it (i.e. not ignoring the user parameter of your updateUser method). I would also make the method transactional, which would allow loading and updating the user in a single transaction, and making the call to save() unnecessary.

Comment: ok I will try it, thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change in  UserController.java:

```
@PostMapping("/{id}/edit")
public String updateUser(
     @ModelAttribute("user") User user,
     @PathVariable("id") Long id) 
{ 
      //user = ur.findOne(id); 
      user.setId(id);
      ur.save(user); 
      return "redirect:/find/" + user.getUserName();
 }
```